# TableView data pass mistake

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I'm following a textbook and it's a bit outdated so I ended up mixing my code with it.
Its a basic app that populates a table view with Cities (london,san francisco,sydney and madrid) and upon clicking it, It should open up a detail view that should display the city as its title and an image of the city with the description, somehow even if I click any cell it shows me "London" with London's picture and description.
Here's my code

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "City.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CityController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a        nib.
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
citys = appDelegate.cities;

}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    City *theCity = [citys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = theCity.cityName;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [citys count];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
@end
```

CityController.m (the detail View)

```
#import "CityController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "City.h"

@implementation CityController

- (id) initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if((self = [super init])){
        index = indexPath;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    City *thisCity = [delegate.cities objectAtIndex:index.row];
    self.title = thisCity.cityName;

    labelDescription.text = thisCity.cityDescription;
    //descriptionView.editable = NO;

    pictureView.image  = thisCity.cityImage;
}

@end
```

City.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface City : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cityName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cityDescription;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *cityImage;

@end
```

Comment: You should learn how to use delegates. Here is the link for Apple's UITableViewDelegate: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/

Answer (score 0):

You don't show in your code how you are calling this method on your `CityController`

```
- (id) initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Therefore `indexPath.row` in `CityController` will always be zero which I'm assuming is the first entry in the cities that relates to London

You need to do something in this method to set the indexPath correctly for the `CityController`

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Yes I know I need to find a way to set the indexPath for CityController, I even tried to code it but it didn't work somehow. Yes I am using storyboards, I even tried to code in my prepareForSegue, I mean I can set the indexPath for my cityController but in my CityController.m it uses 

AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    City *thisCity = [delegate.cities objectAtIndex:index.row]; Which means it doesn't use the citycontroller object to get the values.

Comment: You need to show us how you've tried with the prepareForSegue. That is the correct way of setting this value for your `index` property

Comment: To make it simpler, I removed the function initWithIndexPath and rather just declared a property of NSIndexPath and my prepare for segue looks like this.

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
        CityController *cityVC = [[CityController alloc] init];
        NSIndexPath *in = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [cityVC setIndex:in];
    }
}

Comment: I found the mistake!!
Instead of CityController *cityVC = [[CityController alloc] init]; 
It is CityController *cityVC = segue.destinationViewController;

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be,

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CityController *cityVC = [[CityController alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[self view] addSubview:[cityVC view]];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```